# Filtrado de Seguridad GPOS Windows Server 2019

Tags: seguridad, usercontrol, activedirectory, windows-server-2016, directivas

En nuestro dominio con un WS 2019 queremos organizarnos las GPOs por grupos de AD (dentro de sus OUs separados por nuestras sedes), cuando yo intento crear las GPOs por lo que veo si borro el grupo usuarios autentificados en el filtro de seguridad, aunque meta los grupos a los que quiero que les caiga la GPO, no les funciona las GPOs........... Ahora estamos poniendo en el filtro de seguridad todos los usuarios autentificados y denegando en las delegaciones a los grupos que no queremos que les caiga la GPO…. De momento con las GPOs con registro de usuarios vamos tirando bien. ¿Pero con las GPOS de los equipos... COMO LO HAGO? Tengo que quitar si o si los usuarios autentificados (ya que es tontería por que la política va por pc) y quiero agregar los grupos con los equipos que quiero que le caiga la GPO... pero no me funciona. ¿Sabes cómo puedo solucionar este problema? Por otro lado, he probado a poner en el filtrado de Seguridad el grupo con todos los equipos de dominio, y añadir denegaciones a los grupos con los equipos que no quiero que le caiga la GPO, pero igualmente les cae...
¿Sabéis que es lo que puede ocurrir?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.